# Chrome refuses to load MooTools

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, mootools

Chrome simply refuses to run any Javascript. It shows a `Failed to load resource` in the debug panel, and it highlights this line:

```
<script src="js/mootools/core-1.4.5-full-nocompat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Internet Explorer, Firefox and Opera all run the Javascript appropriately. I'm using a PHP page where the content is captured to a string then returned after having functions performed on it.

Comment: try to load from CDN `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js` and see what happens

Comment: Is this Chrome specific or do you get the same problem in other browsers?

Comment: @holodoc as the question says, it works in IE, FF, and Opera.

Comment: is your content-type ok? what does the network request show as? server response?  failed to load resource is ambiguous.

Comment: I don't mess with Content-Type on this page. There is a piece of code that redirects but that's only if you're not logged in. I don't know how to check the Content-Type return in Chrome but under status for the PHP page it says it failed.

Comment: under the network tab, you will see the requests for all files and it has a Type column. it should say `text/javascript` with a 200 response. if you are doing a PHP redirect, make sure you do `header("Content-type: text/javascript")` before you pipe the file. voting to close as this has nothing to do with programming and it's simply about how to debug page resources.

Comment: There's no PHP in the Javascript file whatsoever. And if you're going to close this, where else am I going to get this resolved?

Comment: google on how to use chrome web inspector, I guess. this is not a code issue. so far you have failed to supply the info on what the server responds with to chrome in particular. good luck

Comment: It responds with Status: (failed) and Type: (text/html) on the PHP page that calls the Javascript. The line given above is where it throws an additional error. I can't find anything about this issue, which is why I posted here in the first place.

Comment: is that the request to the host page or the request caused by the script tag trying to get the mootools file? have you tried using the one from the google CDN as suggested?

Comment: The request to the host page. Using the CDN gets a (cancelled) status and does not change the page's response at all.

Comment: edit your post and post all script tags, in the order they are included and with any attributes like defer. also, make sure none of them lazyload other scripts and don't document.write. try moving mootools-core into head as the first script loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the page wasn't properly reporting the `Content-Length` header before returning the HTML (which is something I shouldn't have to do, seeing as I never touched it). With the captured HTML in the string $html:

```
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($html));
```